# How to map to local resource a to css style link with query part in url

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I want to debug some CSS style which is referenced in the html markup via code

`<link href="css/z-lp.webflow.css?v=1.0.6" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Note presence of **?v=1.0.6** in the href.

I've added a folder to my workspace, which contains `z-lp.webflow.css` file.
Now I'm trying to map this file via "Map to filesystem resource" and it does not work since file can not be found.

[image]

If I map `z-lp.webflow.css` omitting **?v=1.0.6** part, then Chrome does not reflect changes in local file.

Is it possible to map hrefs with query URI in Chrome?

Comment: Are you running Chrome 62? You can check at `chrome://version`. DevTools recently shipped an update to Workspaces in Chrome 63, called [Workspaces 2.0](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes#workspaces). If you download [Chrome Beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html) or [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) you can try it now. I'm curious if the problem is fixed with the latest Workspaces architecture.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Chrome 62. Will update and check again if it works.

Comment: Probably Chrome 63 is rolled out for certain countries only. Mine is 62 and says it is up to date.

Comment: @KayceBasques Yeah, not it is fixed. Post a reply and I will mark it as the correct answer.